# Keep lines in common between two files, but including duplicates

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have two files that look like this:

File 1:

```
rs1
rs2
rs3
```

File 2:

```
rs14 G
rs1 A
rs1 G
rs2 T
rs3 T
rs9 G
```

I want to keep the lines in file 2 that are present in file 1, but including the duplicates. So my result should look something like this:

```
rs1 A
rs1 G
rs2 T
rs3 T
```

I tried to use **comm** and **diff**, but because my second file has two columns I couldn't get the result that I wanted (or I least that's why I think).

Comment: Hi @fedorqui I checked your answer in the other post but I couldn't make it work for my problem. Could you help me? I want the lines matching in file two not the non matching lines.

Comment: `grep -f file1 file2` should be enough.

Comment: You are welcome :) Sorry it wasn't the best duplicate (I couldn't find another one that fits better), I just wanted to make explicit that `grep -f` was the way to go.

Comment: Ok! No problem :). Just another quick thing, my file 1 has actually 60k rows and my file 2 over 60 million rows. grep is taking very long and I have lots of files "1".. Any other way to do it?